# Is SQL Server 2012 and later versions will allow to add Active Directory User Group as Login in SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, active-directory, active-directory-group

I heard that SQL Server 2014 and later versions will not allow to add Active Directory users or groups as login in SQL Server - is that true?

If yes: what is the alternative way to add Active Directory users and groups as logins to SQL Server?

If no: please guide me how to add

Note: I tried to add Active Directory as a login - it's not allowing this, and is throwing some error

Note2: I am able to add the individual users

Comment: What is *some error* ?!?!?!? Please post the **complete and precise** error message you're getting

Comment: `I heard that SQL Server 2014 and later versions will not allow to add Active Directory users or groups as login in SQL Server - is that true?` from where ?

Comment: @marc_s-while adding login in sql server i am getting the error "An object (User, Group, or built-in security proncipal) with the following name cannot be found." here  i am trying to add Active directory-group(i.e contains list of email addresses of users) as a login.. i am not adding individual users...i have checked the group checkbox and selected entire directory option as well...Please refer the link http://www.mssqldestination.com/blog/manjunathcbhat/2014/object-user-group-or-built-security-proncipal-following-name-cannot-be-found -i am facing same issue

Comment: @TheGameiswar- when i am trying to create windows login in sql server2012...please refer the link for clear understanding the problem http://www.mssqldestination.com/blog/manjunathcbhat/2014/object-user-group-or-built-security-proncipal-following-name-cannot-be-found

Comment: @CVENUGOPAL - `I heard that SQL Server 2014 and later versions will not allow to add Active Directory users or groups as login in SQL Server - is that true?` - NO, when using SQL Server Management Studio initially before connecting to DB Engine, it asks for different possible Authentications in which AD login is there, at least for SQL Server 2012 and above!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful- Sorry i am not asking there..i facing this issue while adding user login(while giving access to other users) under SQL Server-->Object Explorer-->Security-->Logins-->right click--> Add New Login. i need to give access to bulk users..so i have all the users list in "active directory"..i need to give insert access to that active directory..while adding active directory as a login i am getting error"An object (User, Group, or built-in security proncipal) with the following name cannot be found."

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, for the same issue i contacted some DB developers they told that SQL Server-2012 and later versions will not allow to add active directory as a User login because of some security concerns.. so i need t check is it true or false...if true is there any alternatives?